# Create a table from selected values of react multi select drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a react select dropDown with users from an api. here is my dropDown

```html
     <Field
              label="Group Members"
              width="18em"
              name="people"
              dropdownLabel="Select members"
              isMulti
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={options.filter(obj => selectedValue.includes(obj.label))}
              closeMenuOnSelect={false}
              options={options}
              hideSelectedOptions={false}
              component={DropDown}
              backgroundColor="#F5F6FB"
             />
```

Here is where i handle change

```html
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(x => x.label) : []);
    
  }
```

I want to automatically create a table based on selected values in the dropdown.The table should consist of users name and email and an action button to delete. I am having an issue rendering the selected names in the table.

Comment: Without code of what you're trying to do with the table, it's difficult to provide an example. However, as a general practice, think of React in 2 phases. Rather than, "when I do this, it changes that", think, "when I do this, it updates some state", and then independently, "given the state, render this content". So, your `handleChange` will record the selected values. The code to render the table doesn't care about where it came from, only that there are some values in the state.

Comment: The first thing you should consider is not just saving `obj.label` in your `selectedValue` because you won't be able to (or it will be difficult to) use its extra properties like `name`, `email` etc later on while rendering it. Also, do you have any `id/id-like` properties in your `user` object? It would be better if you update your question with more code or a reproducible snippet.